# Cordova and ionic relation

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm a little bit confused about Ionic and Cordova :

Correct me if i'm wrong but both of them allows you to create multi mobile devices projects using web techs *(html, css, js)*. In this case, what is really the difference between those two ?

I'm now asked to use both of them for a project which make my previous statement wrong

I'm really confused, send help ! (i already searched in Google and still didn't understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic uses `cordova`. Also it's built on the top of the `Angular` framework. It provides you some UI components. But cordova is a bridge for javascript and each native platform for accessing hardware (like camera or any native feature).

You can build your app with or without ionic.

Comment: Does that mean, that if i want to use Ionic, i should obviously have cordova  installed before the creation of my project ?

Comment: yes, step one of the Ionic getting starter is `npm install -g cordova ionic`, that installs cordova and ionic

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks a lot !

Comment: @MOTZI Without cordova, you can just make an app that runs only in browser.